# Le mot « personne » peut-il être masculin?

Tags: pronoms, genre, accord

J'ai lu dans la Bible française:

> Que **personne** ne dise, lorsqu'**il** est tenté: C'est Dieu qui me tente; ...

C'est une personne qui ne doit pas exister, toutefois, mais le mot comment a-t-il perdu son genre?

Answer (score 12):

Il y a deux mots en français qui s'écrivent [`personne`](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/personne) : un nom féminin, et un pronom. Le nom est grammaticalement féminin, même s'il ne porte aucune indication de genre sur la personne ; le pronom personnel correspondant est donc *elle*. Mais dans cette phrase, c'est le pronom *personne* qui est utilisé (cela se voit à l'absence d'article, entre autres : « que personne ... », pas « qu'une personne ... »).

Le pronom ne porte pas en lui-même de marque de genre. On ne peut pas vraiment dire qu'il ait perdu son genre. Certes, étymologiquement, il provient d'un nom latin, puis ancien français, féminin (on disait : « nulle personne ») ; mais le genre est tombé lorsque le nom s'est transformé en pronom. Grammaticalement, *personne* est de fait neutre. Comme le français n'a pas de neutre, en l'absence de marque de genre, on utilise le masculin.

Lorsque les personnes que pourraient désigner le pronom sont forcément féminines, on trouve quelquefois le féminin, mais plus couramment le masculin. Selon le [*Dictionnaire de l'Académie française*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/academie9/personne),

> Le pronom indéfini *Personne* est du genre masculin. On rencontre néanmoins, dans la langue soutenue, certains cas où l'accord se fait au féminin, lorsque *Personne* équivaut à *aucune femme*. *Pour Pâris, personne n'était plus belle qu'Hélène.*

Answer (score 7):

Le mot n'a pas « perdu son genre », *personne* n'est pas un nom dans cette phrase.
Dans l'exemple que tu donnes *personne* est un déterminant de quantité nulle, donc il ne comporte pas de distinction de genre, par défaut l'accord se fait au masculin (c'est ce qui se passe dans la phrase que tu cites). Cependant l'accord peut se faire au féminin s'il est évident que le pronom s'applique uniquement à des femmes : *personne n'est plus belle que toi, oh ma reine*.
*Nul* suit la même règle. *Rien*, autre déterminant de quantité nulle, ne peut jamais être mis au féminin.

Comment: Je dis encore que le mot a perdu son genre lorsqu'il est devenu un pronom (quoique négatif ou nul) d'un nom.  Il n'a plus de genre comme un nom, mais toutefois, il est le sujet de la phrase, et c'est pourquoi on a besoin de lui accorder un genre, par défaut, comme tu as expliqué, le masculin.  (Je remarque qu'en suedois, le pluriel des adjectifs masculins n'est plus utilisé que rarement, et jamais si le groupe n'est entièrement masculin---au contraire du français.)